# Get an init.d script to wait for internet?

Tags: networking, boot, init.d, bash

I've got an init.d script that starts on boot and all it does it run a shell script.

The script, tries to update a github repo before running the server, the idea being, on a reboot everything updates and starts again.

The problem I'm having is that I'm getting an error:

```
error: Couldn't resolve host 'github.com' while accessing https://<github url>
fatal: HTTP request failed.
```

In my init.d script I'm waiting for networking like so:

```
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $named $syslog $network
```

Does anyone have any ideas of what I could add to the shell script or my init.d to fix this issue?

Comment: I managed to get around it by adding sleep 20 to the shell script (which could probably lower). Just not an ideal way to get this working.

Comment: Hello and welcome. I guess this question would receive better answers at the unix&linux site as it is not really pi specific.

Comment: How about executing your script through rc.local ? It gets executed at the last and everything (MySQL, networking etc) is up by then.

Comment: This could be migrated as is to [U&L](http://unix.stackexchange.com/), but it would be 5 hours back in the queue at this point.  Instead I suggest you just cut and paste it to there.  Raspbian *wheezy* uses Debian's version of SysV init, which has been around since forever (and is probably soon to end up defunct, since Debian are abandoning it; if you have upgraded to *jessie* you might consider learning systemd a bit instead, since that has more of a future).

Comment: BTW, I'm guessing "Required start" does not indicate "successfully completed" if those tasks fork into the background.

Comment: Thanks for input everyone.

Required Start brings up the networking interfaces (I can see eth and wlan in the logs getting assigned IPs), but I think there is an issue with actual internet access or DNS lookup.

I'll have a look at jessie and move this to U&L  - thanks again everyone :)

Comment: From Debian/Raspbian 8 (and RHEL/CentOS 7, and most other major distributions) onward you should no longer use `init.d` scripts but instead create a `systemd` unit. This will allow you easily to wait for the some particular facet of networking to come up.